# How to animate a rig and props simultaneously for Unity?

Tags: animation, unity, rigify, .fbx

I was trying to animate a character rig with a prop and got some unexpected result. The reason why I'm animating a separate prop is because what I have in mind is, in Unity, I'll turn off the prop's `MeshRenderer` and I'll parent whatever "real" prop that I need on that props position. Now, the animations for the rig was exported properly, with a bit of issue. But the props animation somehow got applied to the rig as well. On one of the rig's animation, the left arm did some weird thing and it didn't follow the hand properly.

I'll add my blend file here as I think it might be easier if you guys can see it yourself.
[image]

This is what the model looks in blender.

[image]

Here's what it looks like in Unity(the other side is alright)

[image]

And here's what the animation of the prop looked like in Unity

[image]

I've already seen [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110592/how-to-animate-a-character-with-props-in-blender-and-then-have-these-props-modif) as well and I'm not quite satisfied with it's answer

UPDATE:
I kinda found a workaround for that prop animation affecting the rig. What I did is I just gave the prop it's own bone so the the animation the prop needs only applies to it's own bone. Unfortunately, that weird exported forearm behavior is still there.

UPDATE:

Here's what the model's hierarchy on Unity, I already made the model humanoid:

[image]

UPDATE:

After following the answer below, I realized that my model can't be recognized as humanoid because Unity can't find a head bone. I think I kinda have this problem before as well

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you treating the skeleton as a Humanoid skeleton or a Generic skeleton in Unity? Can you show the bone/game object hierarchy that gets generated? Just drag the character into an empty scene, and expand its hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I already added a screenshot of the game object hierarchy of the model.

Comment: Can you try to make the sword bone a child of the hand bone and test if it makes a difference? For some reason, the MCH bones are getting exported as well. Can you select *Only Deform Bone* when exporting?

Comment: Will try later. But I didn't have that sword bone before and the main rig still have that arm issue

Comment: Yes, but when you didn't, you still had the object there which caused a bigger issue. As far as I know, Humanoid skeletons have strict requirements. Having additional bone hierarchies and extra objects just confuses the automatic process of bone mapping. That's why I am giving you suggestions to remove as many of the extra stuff as possible to make the automatic process figure out the correct mapping without manual intervention.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try the Generic skeleton?

Comment: I downloaded your file, cleaned up a few things, and exported the bare minimum to an FBX file (no weapon is included). I uploaded it to WeTransfer [here](https://we.tl/t-qPHJ7ddGNZ). It imports fine in Blender on my side. Can you verify that it imports fine on your side in Blender and in Unity? If it works, I will write an answer with the steps I followed.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about this. Will try later, I'll surely be able to check this out as I'll have more free time later this evening

Comment: Hi @MrA, I just tried your fbx file and it fixed the arm issue, but has the main model floating issue on the sword_pos animations

Comment: I inspected the FBX file, and it seems that there were indeed more animations in the file. This probably confused Unity once again. I most likely forgot to uncheck some boxes when exporting the FBX file. Anyway, I think I have all the information I need to write an answer. I will do it now.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I've done this previously was to add an extra bone to the deform skeleton for the prop. Since you're using Rigify, this kind of edits will be overwritten if you regenerate the rig. That's why I suggest to do this when you are sure you won't need to regenerate the rig.

The bone you add should preferably be a child of the hand that holds the prop; however, if the prop is expected to switch hands or be mounted on the torso or back, it may be better to make it a child of the root bone. While animating, you can parent it with constraints to whichever bone makes sense depending on what you want to achieve.

The prop mesh you use in Blender will be parented to the bone just to help you visualize the bone's movement, but you won't need to export it, and you won't animate it. You will animate its bone as part of the character rig. In Unity, the animation of the bone prop may get discarded, because no mesh is skinned to it. However, I believe there is an import setting to change this behavior.

Your new mesh in Unity should be instantiated as a child under the prop bone. Make sure to pick a good default position and orientation for the prop bone to eliminate the need to adjust the position and orientation of weapon in Unity after instantiating it under the prop bone.

Your file came with a number of animations. Depending on your FBX export settings, this can lead to issues. I suggest to uncheck *NLA Strips* and *All Actions*. Since your file has many objects, I would also limit the export to *Selected Objects* only which will be the rig and the character only (no prop mesh as mentioned above). A screenshot is attached below.

[image: FBX Export Settings]

I believe the right arm bug was caused by a parenting issue in the bones. In my test, I baked the animation on the deform bones clearing the constraints. Then, I fixed the relationships between the bones to make the rig have a clear hierarchy. I also deleted all bones except the deform bones. The deform bones are on the third layer from the bottom right (layer 29 where the first layer is layer 0).

I am sorry if this is too much to take. Skinned assets are the hardest and trying to add complexity on top of this makes a complex mess.

Comment: Ok, that only deform bones fixed the issue I think, and not including the props as well. And maybe 4.0?

Comment: I am not sure if you mean swords in two hands or a sword that is held by two hands. For the first, you will need an extra bone on both hands. The sword in the right hand will be attached to the extra bone in the right hand. The sword in the left hand will be attached to the extra bone in the left hand. Everything else will be the same. For the second, the original setup will work fine as the weapon will follow one hand. When animating, you will typically add a constraint to parent the other hand to the weapon after placing it where you want on the weapon.

Comment: Just did some additional testing and I think your proposed process made the head disappear so Unity can't recognize the model as humanoid. I'm thinking that maybe I'll just do some ugly stuff on Unity to "animate" the swords and stuff by adding an empty GameObject to the chars hands, parenting the weapons there and coding it's rotation if needed

Comment: All the bone fields are filled in. I can't see the problem.

Comment: Except for the head unfortunately, because if you look at the other screenshot, ORG-spine003 doesn't have any other child bone left except the left/right shoulders

Comment: I see. This is sadly an artifact of how Rigify does parenting for the bones. That's why you ended up with so many MCH bones in your export. In my manual clean-up, I remove those bones and re-establish the deform bone hierarchy to be something that Unity can easily pick up. Honestly, when I use Rigify, I don't use its deform skeleton directly. Instead, I attach my character's skeleton to it using constraints. It an extra step that saves me so much headache in the long run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149959/discussion-between-rminaj-and-mr-a).